# Not Repeat actions in buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, button

I am doing some transitions in some buttons which are going to show 
some content, when you press the buttons the content slide and fadeOut and the other content fadeIin and slide to vew, which is working really good, but when you press the same buttons twice it just slide and fade and then appears again, i would like the buttons to can not be pressed if is already showing the section.

ill leave you the code i am using for the function:

```
    $(".btns-segur-desarr ul").on("click", changeArticule);

function changeArticule (data) {
    var target = data.target.className;
    var secciones = ["#seccion-fuego","#seccion-bateria","#seccion-sismo","#seccion-extintor"];
    $("#" + target).css("right", -"80");

    for (var i = 0; i < secciones.length; i++) {
        if($(secciones[i]).hasClass("aVista")){
            $(secciones[i]).animate({
                right: "40",
                opacity: "0"
            });
        $(secciones[i]).removeClass("aVista");
        }
    };

    $("#" + target).addClass("aVista");
    $("#" + target).animate({
        right:"0",
        opacity: "1"
    })

}
```

I will appreciate if someone could help me getting this i am learning java Script and j query and just got stuck :/

Comment: Provide [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) example.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery's `.one()` binding to make sure an event fires once and only once. However, this would require you to re-bind the event when you want to re-enable the button.

A better solution is to have your event add a class when clicked, and then check for that class to see if it should fire again. For example:
`$(data.target).addClass("clicked")`
and
`if ($(data.target).hasClass("clicked")) return false;`

This would give you a bit more flexibility when you want to re-enable that button.